# Can't scroll through widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a listview filled with Images from firestore, but I noticed it is possible only to scroll when thouching empty space between widgets.

I can't touch image or title and scroll, only with touching empty space.

Is there any way to fix that?

It happens both on web and on anroid phone.

code:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<Widget> listOfPosts = List();

  bool arePostsCreated = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.docs.length; i++) {
            if (!arePostsCreated) {
              listOfPosts.add(Post(snapshot, i));
            }
          }
          arePostsCreated = true;
          return ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: listOfPosts);
        });
  }
}


class Post extends StatelessWidget {
  AsyncSnapshot snap;
  int i;
  Post(this.snap, this.i);

  bool bought = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
        child: ListView(shrinkWrap: true, children: [
          Text(snap.data.docs[i]['title'], textAlign: TextAlign.center),
          Image.network(snap.data.docs[i]['urlPic']),
          if (snap.data.docs[i]['description'] != null)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 5),
              child: Text(snap.data.docs[i]['description'],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            )
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `primary: false,` in your listView, i.e.

```
...
   return ListView(shrinkWrap: true, primary: false, children: listOfPosts);
...
```

Comment: Wrap it inside a `SingleChildScrollView` as well with using above solution.

Comment: I wrapped ListView with SingleChildScrollView, then I wrapped Post with SingleChildScrollView and nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**
I created ListView from widgets which also contained a ListView. I replaced ListView in Post class with Column.